# Save an active colon from within expl3

Tags: expl3, catcodes

Is there a preferred way to realize the following without having to leave expl3 syntax?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% suppose I am within a package here -- else the definition could just be made
% outside of the expl3 scope
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \:
% now expl3 syntax isn't possible any more
\gdef \c_colon_active_tl {:}
\endgroup

% just for showing things are working as expected:
a \c_colon_active_tl {} ~ vs~ a:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\lowercase` trick is always available

Comment: @egreg Only at the primitive level

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual chicken-and-egg problem, solvable with the `\lowercase` trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \^^@
\char_set_lccode:nn { `^^@ } { `: }
\tl_to_lowercase:n { \group_end:
  \tl_const:Nn \c_colon_active_tl { ^^@ }
}

\tl_show_analysis:N \c_colon_active_tl
```

The output is

```
The token list \c_colon_active_tl contains the tokens:
>  : (active character=undefined).
```

(For releases before TeX Live 2017, you will need `\usepackage{l3tl-analysis}` in addition to `\usepackage{xparse}` for this to work.)

---

**UPDATE 2020**

There is now a much better way to do the same (by the way, the code above would not run on recent `expl3` kernels).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
\char_set_active_eq:nN { `: } \scan_stop:
\tl_const:Nx \c_colon_active_tl { \char_generate:nn { `: } { 13 } }
\group_end:

\tl_analysis_show:N \c_colon_active_tl
```

This shows

```latex
The token list \c_colon_active_tl contains the tokens:
>  : (active character=undefined).
```

However, upon defining a meaning for the active colon, using `\c_colon_active_tl` would employ that, because an active character is a macro. The `\scan_stop:` (that is, `\relax`) is used to avoid expansion of the generated active colon.